# Adding escape character to pandas dataframe using python function returning incorrect values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to cleanse the comments column in a data frame and replace non-alpha numeric characters like single quotes with escape characters by passing the data frame to a function. The value returned doesn't have the replaced characters, but returning back as is.

df['comments']:

```
didn't
should've
```

`def cleanser(data):
     clean_data = data.str.strip().replace("'", "\''")).replace("$", "\$")
     return clean_data`

`df = df.apply(lambda x: cleanser(x)))`

The above function returns below dataframe without any change.

df['comments']:

`didn't
should've`

Please advise what is wrong with the function and what changes i must make to get below result.

Expected result df['comments']:

```
didn''t
should''ve
```

Comment: Can't you just do `replace("'", "''")` if you need two single quotes?

Comment: @Psidom - That didn't work. The function returned `didn't` instead of `didn''t`

Comment: You have a bug in your code. `data.str.strip().replace("'", "\''"))`, need another `str` before `replace`. `data.str.strip().str.replace("'", "''")`.